# how to run the same test in Jenkins twice

Tags: java, jenkins

I need to run some test classes few times (with different jvm options) within the same build and reflect a result in the build.
Each run should be tagged according to some logic

right now when I run the test 2 times only one latest result is reflected and the rest are skipped,

so is it possible to set up Jenkins in the way I need?

in a nutshell:

ex. the below gets ran in few threads

`()-> {
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sbt "test:testOnly somePackage.SomeClassTest"");
}`

the Jenkins job triggers the above main method and runs SomeClassTest few times,

I need to get the result for each run of SomeClassTest  in Jenkins job

is such approach doable at all?

Comment: `right now when I run the test 2 times only one latest result is reflected` - so how are you running your tests now? what is your build tool (maven/gradle/ant/..)? How is result collected (junit XML reports)?

Comment: I collect result by using some plugins in post-build actions like jmh report/junit test report etc

I would expect to see the result like 
- tag: run 1 ----result
- tag run 2 ----result

Comment: the build tool is sbt,  but tooling is not that important and can be changed

Comment: Some code would help a lot.

Comment: ex. the below gets ran in few threads

()-> {
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sbt "test:testOnly somePackage.SomeClassTest"");
}

the Jenkins job triggers the above main method and runs SomeClassTest few times,

I need to get the result for each run of SomeClassTest  in Jenkins